# Interactive horizontal rules for vega altair

Tags: altair

I want to plot upper and lower limits for a number of metrics over uids. These upper and lower limits are expectations and are single value for each metrics.
I want to make it interactive such that when clicking on the legend, the plot only shows one metrics and their upper and lower limits.

The effort below does what I want to do but with undesirable side effects.

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'dimension_x': np.random.random(10),
        'dimension_y': np.random.random(10),
        'dimension_z': np.random.random(10),}

melt_data = pd.DataFrame(data).reset_index(names='uid').melt(id_vars=['uid'], var_name='metric', value_name='value')

limit = {'metric': ['dimension_x',
                    'dimension_y',
                    'dimension_z'],
         'upper_limit': [0.95, 0.85, 0.9],
         'lower_limit': [0.05, 0.15, 0.1]}
limit_df = pd.DataFrame(limit, columns=["metric", "upper_limit", "lower_limit"])

melt_y = melt_data.merge(limit_df, on='metric', how='left')


selection = alt.selection_point(fields=['metric'], bind='legend')

base = alt.Chart(melt_y)

chart = base.mark_line().encode(
    alt.X('uid'),
    alt.Y('value:Q').scale(zero=False, clamp=True),
    alt.Color('metric'),
    opacity=alt.condition(selection, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.2))
).add_selection(selection).transform_filter(
    selection
).properties(
    width=800,
    height=400
)

limit = base.transform_fold(["upper_limit", "lower_limit"],
                                  as_=["limit_type", "limit_value"]
).mark_rule(
    strokeDash=[2, 2],
    strokeWidth=2
).encode(
    #y=alt.datum(y_max, type="quantitative")
    y="mean(limit_value):Q",
    color="limit_type:N"
).add_selection(selection).transform_filter(
    selection
)
chart = chart + limit
chart.serve()
```

Side effects:

1. I join the limits and the data on metrics into melt_y. This creates a column with a lot of duplicate entry. Is there a way to read the `limit` dict and use alt.datum to plot two horizontal rule based on `selection`?
2. When nothing is selected on the legend, the limits are averaged across metrics categories, which is meaningless. The limit shouldn't be plot when nothing is selected on the legend.

Comment: Please create a fully reproducible example by also providing sample data